# Program cannot find RequestEntity class even though jar is included with compile

Tags: java, http-post, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-httpclient

I build a very simple test program to submit an HTTP Post to a webserver with an XML payload.  I'm including the `jar` file `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar` which contains the RequestEntity class, but when I run the program I get the following error and I cannot determine why it cannot find the class.

My `javac` command:

```
 javac -verbose -d classes -sourcepath src -cp lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar; src\testpartstorepost\PostXML2.java
```

Verbose output shows it load the `RequestEntity.class`

```
[parsing started src\testpartstorepost\PostXML2.java]
[parsing completed 32ms]
[search path for source files: src]
[search path for class files: ***SNIP***
[loading java\io\File.class(java\io:File.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\HttpClient.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient:HttpClient.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods\FileRequestEntity.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods:FileRequestEntity.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods\PostMethod.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods:PostMethod.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods\RequestEntity.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods:RequestEntity.class)]
[loading java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class)]
[loading java\lang\String.class(java\lang:String.class)]
[loading java\lang\Exception.class(java\lang:Exception.class)]
[checking testpartstorepost.PostXML2]
[loading java\lang\Throwable.class(java\lang:Throwable.class)]
[loading java\net\URI.class(java\net:URI.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods\EntityEnclosingMethod.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods:EntityEnclosingMethod.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods\ExpectContinueMethod.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient\methods:ExpectContinueMethod.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\HttpMethodBase.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient:HttpMethodBase.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\HostConfiguration.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient:HostConfiguration.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\HttpMethod.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient:HttpMethod.class)]
[loading java\lang\System.class(java\lang:System.class)]
[loading java\io\PrintStream.class(java\io:PrintStream.class)]
[loading java\io\FilterOutputStream.class(java\io:FilterOutputStream.class)]
[loading java\io\OutputStream.class(java\io:OutputStream.class)]
[loading java\lang\Error.class(java\lang:Error.class)]
[loading java\io\IOException.class(java\io:IOException.class)]
[loading java\lang\RuntimeException.class(java\lang:RuntimeException.class)]
[loading org\apache\commons\httpclient\HttpException.class(org\apache\commons\httpclient:HttpException.class)]
[loading java\lang\StringBuilder.class(java\lang:StringBuilder.class)]
[loading java\lang\AbstractStringBuilder.class(java\lang:AbstractStringBuilder.class)]
[loading java\lang\CharSequence.class(java\lang:CharSequence.class)]
[loading java\io\Serializable.class(java\io:Serializable.class)]
[loading java\lang\Comparable.class(java\lang:Comparable.class)]
[loading java\lang\StringBuffer.class(java\lang:StringBuffer.class)]
[wrote classes\testpartstorepost\PostXML2.class]
```

But when I run the program I get the following:

```
D:\java testpartstorepost/PostXML2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: testpartstorepost/PostXML2.  Program will exit.
```

I can provide the java source too if needed.  I cannot determine why the program cannot find the RequestEntity

**EDIT**

If I change my java call to point to the right `classpath` I get further, think this one is solved.

```
java -cp .;..\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar; testpartstorepost/PostXML2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your classpath is correct ? Its relative path, so it matters what directory you start javac in.

Comment: That was it, the classpath at execution was set incorrectly.  I assumed if I compiled the java program with the classpath I wouldnt need to include it at runtime, but I was incorrect.